# Swapping the Motherboard of Dell N5010

Tags: motherboard, bios, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell N5010 laptop. It had an integrated graphics card in it which went bad. So, I had to get my motherboard swapped for a new one. The swapping was done by a local repair shop.

I am now having doubts about the motherboard that they put and am thinking if a new motherboard was indeed put or they just soldered back a new video card. So I want to clarify somethings. I have following questions:-

1. Does BIOS come attached with the motherboard or can it be used again like CPU. And if it comes attached then would the motherboard change lead to a change in the service tag of my laptop ?
2. Is there any other way I can check whether they really did the swap or not ?

   If it helps, I do remember my previous service tag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop is based on Intel Core CPU, so it has GPU integrated in the CPU, not on motherboard. Your motherboard was probably left untouched, they have just replaced CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the service centre which has done this hob for you about whether they change a MB or what did they change/do. You have a right to ask and know. Don't let them be a black box.